# bouncy castle (for children to jump and play on)

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I have been asked by the child of a neighbour to translate this into Latin. I am finding it difficult apart from the fact that Latin doesn’t seem to have a good word for ‘bouncy’ apart from ‘salio’ and compounds & in any case it’s not the castle which does the bouncing! There is the adjective ‘saltatorius’, which perhaps could be used. But the best I could come up with is castrum/ castellum inflabile (lusorium). However ‘inflabilis’ is a late Latin adjective and a relative clause would seem somewhat cumbersome:- castrum lusorium quod inflari potest (possit? if the relative clause is considered to be generic). I prefer the latter, because, though long-winded, it seems (mea quidem sententia) to be better Latin. I would welcome suggestions from colleagues.